# Вербальное моделирование деяний и явлений

Tags: лингвистика

С точки зрения атеиста, каждое событие квалифицируется как деяние и/или явление.

**Вопрос 1**: Верно ли, что английское предложение "Cain **is looking at**  Abel." моделирует деяние, а английское предложение "Abel **sees** Cain." моделирует явление?

**Вопрос 2**: Как моделируются деяния и явления в русском языке?

Answer (score 1):

Класс! Никогда не говорила о языке, используя такие категории. Ничего не могу сказать об английском. В русском ' я иду' - деяние? Выражается личной формой глагола. 'Дождь идет' - явление. Тоже личная форма. Но можно и ' дождит' - безличный глагол. ' Дождь.' - номинативное предложение. Получается, что средств для выражения явлений больше, чем для выражения деяний. Вот что пока пришло на ум.

Comment: Чрезвычайно интересно! А как быть с такими словами как "скок-скок", "полёт", "разрушая" и "летящий"? Это не глаголы, но отглагольные образования. Считать ли их способом выражения деяния?

Comment: Я почему - то сразу начала рассматривать предикаты. Может, потому, что в вопросе говорится о событиях?

Comment: Пасмурно. Тихо. Прохладно. "Моделируется" ли явление категорией состояния? Мне кажется, да.

Comment: Согласна. А что же все-таки с "деяниями"?

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.